# How to list the details of a selected item in a dropdown list to show underneath using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm working on a form to remove Wines from a database using PDO. At the moment I am having issues with the jQuery code in listing further details based on dropdown list selection. The code allows a user to select a wine from a dropdown list and once the wine is selected, the area underneath will list the details of that chosen wine, such as wineID, wineCountry, wineColour etc. The dropdown list is showing up fine but the area with the further details underneath aren't showing. I have written similar code prior to this and had no issues.

Remove Wine Page

```
<!--JQuery Library-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<?php
  $wineListing = [];
        $sql= 'SELECT *
                FROM Wine';
        $result = $pdo->query($sql);

        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $wineListing[$row['description']][] = $row;
        }
  ?>

<div class="removeWine">
 <table>
  <center> <span>Wine Management<span></center><P><P><P>
   <hr>
  <center> <span>Remove Wine<span></center><P><P><P>
  </br>

<?php if ($status): ?>
  <p style="color: green"><?=$status?></p>
<?php endif ?>

    <form action= "" method="POST">
    <tr>
      <td> View Wines:     </td>

      <td>
        <select id='wineNameSelect' name='wineName'>

          <?php

          foreach($wineListing as $wineID => $description) {

            $json = json_encode($description);

            echo "<option data-descriptions='$json' value='" . $description[0]['wineID'] ."'>" . $wineID ."</option>";
          }
          ?>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
      Wine Details
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul id="results">
          </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table><p><br>

  <center><input type="submit" name= "removeWineButton" value="Remove Wine"></center><p><p><p><p>
  </form>
```

Script Tag

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#wineNameSelect").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>   </option>");
});
$('#wineNameSelect').change(function(){
var description = $(this).find(':selected').data('description');
console.log(description);
var content = "";
$.each(description, function(key,value){
  content += "<li>"+value.wineID+"</li>"
        +"<li>"+value.description+"</li>"
});
  $("#results").html(content);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind onchange event on your select tag and then fire up an ajax call to retrieve the details of the selected wine, pass through the wine id in your ajax call. Kindly see code below.

```
$("#wineNameSelect").on("change", function() {
     var id = $(this).data("wine-id");
    $.ajax({
    url: "url_to_wine_details.php",
    type:"GET",
    data: {"id", id},
    success : function(data) {
      // parse result in this case the data variable
      // append them to your ul#results

      }
    });

});
```

I've added wine-id attribute on your select tag

Comment: Hi, I've removed my original code between the script tags and added yours. It's not working still.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I forgot to add my script tags. I've modified my original post to reflect this. Can you have a look?

Comment: Sure. Where is it? Sorry for the late response.

Comment: It's in the bottom of my original post

Comment: Is it working? I mean your code, is it working now? Have you tried it already?

Comment: Can you try to alert the var id. Let us see what's in it.

Comment: Can you just message me or chat?